# Calculate Average values in a JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, shell, average, jq

I am working with a JSON file of this format:

```
  {
  "Response" : {
    "TimeUnit" : [ 1516298400000, 1516302000000, 1516305600000, 1516309200000, 1516312800000, 1516316400000 ],
    "metaData" : {
      "errors" : [ ],
      "notices" : [ "Source:Postgres", "Limit applied: 14400", "PG Host:ruappg0ro.apigeeks.net", "Metric with Avg of total_response_time was requested. For this a global avg was also computed with name global-avg-total_response_time", "query served by:88bec25a-ef48-464e-b41d-e447e3beeb88", "Table used: edge.api.faxgroupusenondn012.agg_api" ]
    },
    "stats" : {
      "data" : [ {
        "identifier" : {
          "names" : [ "apiproxy" ],
          "values" : [ "test" ]
        },
        "metric" : [ {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "sum(message_count)",
          "values" : [ 28.0, 129.0, 24.0, 20.0, 71.0, 30.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "avg(total_response_time)",
          "values" : [ 312.57142857142856, 344.2480620155039, 374.2083333333333, 381.1, 350.67605633802816, 363.8 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "sum(is_error)",
          "values" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "global-avg-total_response_time",
          "values" : [ 349.5860927152318 ]
        } ]
      }, {
        "identifier" : {
          "names" : [ "apiproxy" ],
          "values" : [ "test2" ]
        },
        "metric" : [ {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "sum(message_count)",
          "values" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 137.0, 100.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "avg(total_response_time)",
          "values" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 237.4375, 198.02189781021897, 189.44 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "sum(is_error)",
          "values" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 137.0, 100.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "global-avg-total_response_time",
          "values" : [ 197.12252964426878 ]
        } ]
      }, {
        "identifier" : {
          "names" : [ "apiproxy" ],
          "values" : [ "appdyn" ]
        },
        "metric" : [ {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "sum(message_count)",
          "values" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 137.0, 98.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "avg(total_response_time)",
          "values" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 170.0, 161.57664233576642, 149.16326530612244 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "sum(is_error)",
          "values" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 137.0, 98.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "global-avg-total_response_time",
          "values" : [ 157.0081300813008 ]
        } ]
      }, {
        "identifier" : {
          "names" : [ "apiproxy" ],
          "values" : [ "AppDyn" ]
        },
        "metric" : [ {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "sum(message_count)",
          "values" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "avg(total_response_time)",
          "values" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39.333333333333336, 0.0, 0.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "sum(is_error)",
          "values" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
        }, {
          "env" : "test",
          "name" : "global-avg-total_response_time",
          "values" : [ 39.333333333333336 ]
        } ]
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

and would like to calculate the average of all values under:  `"name" : "avg(total_response_time)"` for each `identifier`iteratively.

I have tried a few attempts and I really don't know how to proceed as the count of the `identifiers` and the `avg(total_response_time)` varies.

> ```
> for identifier in $(cat response4.json | jq -r  '.[].stats.data[].identifier.values' | sed 's/[][]//g' | sed
> ```
>
> 's/"//g'); do
>         echo ${identifier}
>
> ```
> avg_response_time=$(cat response4.json | jq -r  '.[].stats.data[].metric[]') #don't know how to iterate through the 
> done
> ```

Any help/idea will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In general, you should try to do more logic in jq and less logic in shell. There's no reason you can't have just one jq invocation return one tab-separated line per each identifier/avg pair.

Comment: that said, this is far from a [mcve], since it doesn't currently contain enough information to allow an answer's correctness to be tested. Ideally, you should provide (1) a version of the input data with all content irrelevant to the question removed, and (2) correct/desired output given that input.

Comment: BTW, as a general note -- don't ever use `cat` if you don't have to. `jq .
 <input.json` or `jq . input.json` are both more efficient than `cat input.json | jq .`; for programs like `sort` where an optimized implementation can have multiple threads process different subsets of the file concurrently (but only when they're given a seekable file, and *not* when given a pipeline), the difference is even bigger.

Comment: For example (of why this isn't particularly testable as currently written) -- I don't see **any** values here with an "env" other than "test", so if we're supposed to also be generating averages for `test2` or `appdyn` or `AppDyn`... which data, *exactly*, goes into each of those averages?

Comment: I did end up writing an answer here -- but at the same time, I'm feeling guilty for rewarding a question that's so far behind what our community standards call for. Please, **please** try to write questions that comply with the [MCVE] definition (and otherwise don't fall afoul of any of the categories listed under the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)) in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jq -r '
    .[].stats.data[]
    | (.identifier.values[]) as $identifier
    | (.metric[]
       | select(.name == "avg(total_response_time)")
       | .values
      ) as $values
    | [$identifier, ($values | add) / ($values | length)]
    | @tsv
    ' <test.json
```

...yields:

```
test    354.43398004304896
test2   104.14989963503649
appdyn  80.1233179403148
AppDyn  6.555555555555556
```

Answer (score 1):

First, for clarity, here is a stream-oriented helper function:

```
def average(s): 
  reduce s as $x (null; .sum += $x | .n += 1)
  | if . == null then null else .sum / .n end;
```

Next, we have a choice.  We can either treat each item in the .stats.data array individually, or we can group the items by the value of .identifier.  In the example, the results would be the same (except possibly for the ordering), but let us consider here the two cases separately:

#### Average per item in .stats.data

```
.Response.stats.data[]
| {id: (.identifier.values),
   average: average(.metric[]
     | select(.name == "avg(total_response_time)")
     | .values[]) }
```

#### Group by .identifier

```
.Response.stats.data
| group_by(.identifier)[]
| {id: (.[0].identifier.values),
   average: (.[].metric[] 
     | select(.name == "avg(total_response_time)") 
     | .values[] ) }
```

#### Output

```
{"id":["test"],"average":354.43398004304896}
{"id":["test2"],"average":104.14989963503649}
{"id":["appdyn"],"average":80.1233179403148}
{"id":["AppDyn"],"average":6.555555555555556}
```